# Smallest interval of *k* elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array of numbers and an integer *k* smaller or equal than the size of the array, I have to define an algorithm that computes the smallest interval (defined as the difference between first and last element) such that *k* elements lie within this interval. It should run in O(n*log(n)).

I came up with this solution:

(1) Sort the array and start from the first element

(2) Compute the difference between this element and the one at array[i + (k-1)]

(3) Update result if smaller and got to array[i + 1].

It seems to work but I do not know if it is O(n*log(n)). I know that sort is O(n*log(n)) but the problem is with the for loop I am using.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the order of elements?

Comment: @Shubham I do not know actually. There is an example: the initial array is not sorted but then the solution is a sorted array with elements that are not adjacent in the initial one.

Comment: Your algorithm is n(log(n)).  The final step is walking through the array, one element at a time.  This step is O(n), so the sort dominates the performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment (in algorithm analysis). If so I'd expect the required result to be first and last index within the original data. Sorting would be no option without tracking the positions then.

Comment: @RuDevel "For example, if A = {3.1, 6.2, 10, 5.8, 1.0, 2.2, 6.0, 7.3} and k = 4, then the smallest interval containing k elements is [5.8, 7.3] of size 1.5, which contains the elements {5.8, 6.0, 6.2, 7.3}."

Comment: Good example- if that is what you need I'd add that description to your question.

Comment: @RuDevel Yes. But in this case my solution is correct, I guess.